# In Xunit test database Views are not populating in in-memory DB

Tags: xunit.net

As part of Code coverage in one of project require to cover all service code where we have used hard coded queries .Unit test written using XUnit and services have views used for reading data. When we populated dependent tables for view and execute view it written zero count. There are no permission issue or complex logic in views.
Using entity framework 5.0.14 DB first approach and .net framework 5 .

Can someone help if this is overall issue with view to execute in in-memory db ?

view to populate with records

Comment: please can anyone help ..